# Listview open in new activity to display horizontal image

Tags: android, listview

ListView open new activity

Hi guys my problem is how to display horizontal image in new activity using ListView.But the very big problem is when i click "ONE" of the list item its probably going back to main menu,,I've search in the same problem but its not work so .what should i do?
This is my MainMenu class

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
}
public void Click(View view){
    Intent fors = new Intent(this, ListViewOfMunicipalities.class);
    startActivity(fors);
}
```

MainMenu xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainMenu">



<Button
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ALBAY MABUHAY"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="Click"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
    android:background="#51010101"
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

It will going to ListViewOfMunicipalties

```
public class ListViewOfMunicipalities extends AppCompatActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_of_municipalities);

    String[] Municipalities = {" Tiwimunicipalitity", "TabacoMunicipality", "MalinaoMunicipality"};

    ListAdapter forsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Municipalities);
    ListView mlistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mlistView);
    mlistView.setAdapter(forsAdapter);

    mlistView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                    switch( position ) {
                        case 0:  Intent TiwiActivity;
                            TiwiActivity = new Intent(ListViewOfMunicipalities.this, TiwiMunicipality.class);
                            startActivity(TiwiActivity);
                            break;
                        case 1:  Intent TabacoActivity = new Intent(ListViewOfMunicipalities.this,  TabacoMunicipality.class);
                            startActivity(TabacoActivity);
                            break;
                            default:

                    }

                }
            }
    );

}
```

when i click the case 0 its going to TiwiMunicipality.class and when i click case 1 which is the TabacoMunicipality.class,,its probably going back to main menu and that was the error :( .here are the code of TiwiMunicipality.class

```
public class TiwiMunicipality extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tiwi_municipality);
    Intent TiwiActivity=new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, TiwiActivity);
    //finish();
}
```

the xml of TiwiMunicipality

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.millena.thesisapplication.TiwiMunicipality">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <HorizontalScrollView
       android:layout_width="300dp"
       android:layout_height="250dp">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="350dp"
           android:layout_height="250dp">

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="300dp"
               android:layout_height="250dp"
               android:id="@+id/img"
               android:background="@mipmap/a" />

           <ImageView
               android:layout_width="300dp"
               android:layout_height="250dp"
               android:id="@+id/imageView2"
               android:background="@drawable/ganda" />

       </LinearLayout>

   </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is the TabacoMunicipality.class

```
public class TabacoMunicipality extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tabaco_municipality);
    Intent TabacoActivity=new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, TabacoActivity);
    //finish();
}
```

The xml of TabacoMunicipality

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.millena.thesisapplication.TabacoMunicipality">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="@string/TABACO"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp">


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:background="@drawable/ahmm" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:background="@drawable/pogi" />
    </LinearLayout>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

My AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity
        android:name=".ListViewOfMunicipalities"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_list_view_of_municipalities" >

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainMenu"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".TiwiMunicipality"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tiwi_municipality" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TiwiMunicipality" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".TabacoMunicipality"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tabaco_municipality" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TabacoMunicipality" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MalinaoMunicipality"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_malinao_municipality" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MalinaoMunicipality" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>



</application>
```

what's my error here guys?please help me because it is my thesis project :(

Comment: why are you using `setresult()` when you haven't started the activity for `startactivityforresult` ??

Comment: what am going to do?

Comment: why are you using setresult()?